# Mortal Kombat X for Android - new tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, there have been two questions asked about Mortal Kombat X for Android:

- [Are Mortal Kombat X for PC and android different games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300420/are-mortal-kombat-x-for-pc-and-android-different-games)
- [How do I earn new cards in Mortal Kombat X?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300360/how-do-i-earn-new-cards-in-mortal-kombat-x)

Should there be a tag for Mortal Kombat X for Android? Are the games different enough (one of the questions is kind of asking that)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more research, it seems that the Android (and iOS) versions are basically card versions of Mortal Kombat X. Thus, we should just create a new [mortal-kombat-x-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-x-mobile) tag.

Comment: See the first link in my question. The answer to that question states it's a different game completely.  Are we sure?

Comment: @TimmyJim well, the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_X?wprov=sfsi1) lists it as just a port. However, after doing more research, it seems erroneous to have listed it that way. The Android/iOS version does, indeed, seem to be quite different. I will update my answer. I believe that questions specifically asking about the mobile version should use a separate tag.

Comment: Agreed. I've since created that tag and updated those two linked questions to include them.